# How can you use indicator titration to determine the pH of a complex solution like ocean water if at all

Tags: acid-base, titration

Could you measure the pH of ocean water by using a strong acid-weak base titration? I was thinking that you could set up a standard titration with ocean water as the "unknown", and drip the known HCl solution into it until the equivalence point but I don't know you would go about figuring out the equivalence point and consequently the pH of ocean water using this method. Is it even possible?

Comment: Titration doesn't measure pH in the first place, much like a tape-line doesn't measure weight.

Comment: I realize that titration isn't a direct method by which to measure pH but can't you use it to determine OH-/H+ concentrations and calculate pH using that?

Comment: No. Well, unless you know for sure there is one single fully dissociated acid (or base) in your solution. In that case it will work like you said. Otherwise it won't.

Comment: This might help: https://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-ph-and-titratable-acidity/

Comment: Titration does not determine content of H+ nor OH-, as sea water is a kind of a diluted pH  CO2/HCO3- buffer.